# Run mysqldump from dotnet runtime error -1073741515

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a backup of my mysql databases using Azure Functions. Everything works fine when I run mysqldump.exe in the terminal (SCM/Kudu) but when I run the exact same command from dotnet using `Process.Start`, the app exits immediately with exit code `-1073741515`.

This is how I run the code from the terminal using Kudu. This command is literally the command that is also executed from dotnet because I copied it from the logs:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\mysqldump\win\mysqldump.exe --host=*** --user=*** --password=*** --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false --routines --hex-blob --result-file=d:\home\site\temp\697ce5ad-0bba-4de1-b070-7c65283a3941 --verbose ***
```

Result:
Process exits with exit code `0` and the backup file is created as expected.

This is how I run the command from dotnet:

```cs
var mysqlDump = "D:\home\site\wwwroot\mysqldump\win\mysqldump.exe";
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = mysqlDump,
    Arguments =
        $"--host={dbHost} --user={dbUser} --password={dbPassword} --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false --routines --hex-blob --result-file={sqlPath}{(mysqlDumpVerbose ? " --verbose" : "")} {message.Database}",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data))
    {
        log.LogInformation(e.Data);
    }
};
process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data))
    {
        log.LogError(e.Data);
    }
};

try
{
    log.LogInformation($"Executing '{startInfo.FileName} {startInfo.Arguments}'...");
    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 10);
    if (process.ExitCode != 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(
            $"Process did not exit with code 0 (zero). Actual exit code: {process.ExitCode}");
    }
}
finally
{
    log.LogInformation($"Cleaning up files...");
    TryDeleteFile(sqlPath, log);
    TryDeleteFile(sqlCleanedPath, log);
    TryDeleteFile(zipPath, log);
}
```

Output:

```
[Information] Executing 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\mysqldump\win\mysqldump.exe --host=*** --user=*** --password=*** --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false --routines --hex-blob --result-file=d:\home\site\temp\697ce5ad-0bba-4de1-b070-7c65283a3941 --verbose ***'...
[Error] Exception: Process did not exit with code 0 (zero). Actual exit code: -1073741515
```

These are the versions:

```
mysqldump version: 8.0.23 (8.0.26 and 8.0.27 don't work either)
dotnet runtime: 3.1
Azure functions runtime: 3
```

I also tried a 5.7.* version of mysqldump which actually starts but then crashes with exit code 2 when it reached a certain table in the database, regardless of how I execute the command.

I really have no clue why the exact same command does work in the terminal but not work from dotnet or why mysqldump version 5.7.35 does start but 8.0.* doesn't. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I'm not a Windows developer, I just did a web search for "Actual exit code: -1073741515". I found several instances of people with the same question (not always about mysqldump, but other commands). The answers suggest that this exit code indicates the command you ran could not find some DLL's it needed, or else didn't have permission to use those DLL's.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for researching online. I also got a few hits on google pointing into that direction but I don't think it's because of missing dll's since the command works when I run it from the Kudu terminal. It could be permission related but that would be a very specific issue because of reasons mentioned before and because mysqldump 5.6.35 does run when called from dotnet.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with mysql odbc connector?